# Turning the values of a dictionary into a vector

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I am trying to turn the numerical values of a dictionary into a vector because the order of the values matter. I have done something similar before but it isn't working here for some reason, any help would be appreciated.

```
g_dict = dict()
g_dict['E*S'] = -1.502
g_dict['S']   = -1.720
g_dict['E']      = 0.802
g_dict['I*E']  = -2.444
g_dict['P'] = -2.377
g_dict['I']   = -0.389
g_dict['I*E*S']  = 0.703


for spc in species:
    g_vec[species.index(spc)] = g_dict[spc]
```

It is telling me that the float cant take this item assignment if that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
g_vec = [g_dict[s] for s in species]
```